# Mongo query doesnt recognise empty records

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm going through my collection and returning coordinate information, however when it hits an empty record it throws this error:

```
a=get_coords(doc['coordinates']['coordinates'])
print a
```

This is the function get_coords:

```
def get_coords(doc):
    if doc == None:
        pass
    else:
        longs, lat = doc

        return lat, longs
```

The error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

This then stops my query and no further records are returned.

How can I prevent this from happening, what I mean is I still want it to carry on searching for other records rather than stopping with this error message.

Thanks

Thanks for both answers they both helped. I was able to get it done by:

```
if doc['coordinates']==None:
    pass
else: 
    b=get_coords(doc['coordinates']['coordinates'])
    print b
```

I do this after first checking that there is indeed a doc in the collection. It now seems to print all existing coordinates in the collection.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're printing `b`, since that's not defined in the above code. Maybe you mean `a`?

Either way, you should be able to do:

```
if doc==None:
   pass
else:
   a=get_coords(doc['coordinates']['coordinates'])
   print b
```

or whatever you want to do with `doc`. If some `doc` items don't have `coordinates` you'll need to do something similar for that.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the typo with var b. I've updated my function with your suggestion and it still sends the same error.

Comment: Ok, thanks for updating! It's still returning an error because you can't call `doc['coordinates']['coordinates']` on a NoneType... so I'll try and edit my answer to suit your needs... wait, try my actual code: that is, don't use the `if` statement in the `get_coords` function, but rather how I did, or in a similar way.

Comment: I will try to change my answer if it still doesn't work for you, but please try doing it closer to my answer first: not asking for `doc['coordinates']['coordinates']` until *after* you know `doc` exists.

Comment: Glad to assist! Thanks for selecting my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Will `doc` always have a `coordinates` attribute? If so, will that dictionary always have another `coordinates` attribute? Assuming `doc` will always be dictionary (even just a blank one), you can try this:

```
In [90]: def get_coords(doc):
   ....:     if doc.get('coordinates', None):
   ....:         if doc['coordinates'].get('coordinates', None):
   ....:             return doc['coordinates']['coordinates']
   ....:     return None, None
   ....:

In [91]: doc
Out[91]:
{'coordinates': {u'coordinates': [-81.453134399999996, 28.5287337],
                 u'type': u'Point'}}

In [92]: get_coords(doc)
Out[92]: [-81.453134399999996, 28.5287337]

In [93]: new_doc = {'coordinates': {u'type': u'Point'}}

In [94]: get_coords(new_doc)
Out[94]: (None, None)

In [95]: empty_doc = {}

In [96]: get_coords(empty_doc)
Out[96]: (None, None)
```

Notice that the `return` value is two items, so when you call the function, you need to be prepared to accept two return items. If there is no `coordinates` in `doc`, it will return `None, None`.

```
In [101]: lat, long = get_coords(doc)

In [102]: lat
Out[102]: -81.453134399999996

In [103]: long
Out[103]: 28.5287337
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, yes doc will have a coordinates attribute and one within that. I like the way you solved this. I'll find it helpful.

Comment: @user94628 No problem :) Also, a quick Python tip - if you ever have a comparison like `if x == None`, you can just say `if not x`, which is a bit more Pythonic.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm trying to be more pythonic, but still trying to break Java habits.

Comment: @user94628 Once you start using it more you'll wonder how you did anything else :)

Answer (score 1):

You also could use exception handling to rewrite `get_coords()` function like this:

```
def get_coords(doc):
    try:
        longs, lat = doc
        return lat, longs
    catch TypeError:
        return None, None
```